# App compatibility with Android devices

Tags: android, google-play

There is an application which can not be runed on particular devices. I have this in Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

And it works on HTC sensation with Android 4.0, but for some reason it is not compatible with Samsung Galaxy Tablet 2 7.0. (Android 4)

When I upload it in Android market, also I can see that the Tablet is not supported.

I can not understand the reason, can you please let me know why?

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    package="test.newversion"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you request hardware features or screen sizes in your manifest

Comment: @Henry , No I don't think so. Thanks for your comment. I added the whole manifest file, at the end of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some permissions implicitly add requirements on the hardware. For example [the docu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) for `CAMERA` says:

> This will automatically enforce the  manifest element for all camera features. If you do not require all camera features or can properly operate if a camera is not available, then you must modify your manifest as appropriate in order to install on devices that don't support all camera features.

If you don't need all, add explicit `uses-feature` elements with `android:required="false"`

Comment: yes, adding this to my manifest included 660 more devices to the compatibility list <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

Answer (score 0):

try to give a luck to the following in manifest if not yet added

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"
/>
```

change it according to your criteria

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is the permissions that are creating a filter which makes the marketplace removes some Tablets.

For e.g. you have the PHONE permissions in your manifest and if the Tablets do not have a phone capability, then they will not be compatible. As Henry suggested, you might look at the `uses-feature` with the `android:required="false"`.

I suggest you review the `AndroidManifest.xml` carefully and proceed from there.